# How to separate the number and string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the string from the front end which contains both string and number Eg: `"L'Oreal Paris L'Huile Nail Paint, 224 Rose Ballet, 13.5ml"`.

Now I want to separate the `13.5ml` to `13.5` as one value and `ml` as another value to insert the value in the backend table.

Comment: Does it follow always some format? What does your code do? What does it print?

Comment: How is the code to know that you want `(13.5, "ml")` separated out, but not `(224,"Rose")`? Will there always be a unit of measure?

Comment: @Ivan This code will remove all the text and it will print the 13.5 ml as an output.But i need the space between the 13.5ml

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `re.findall` with the regex pattern `\d+(?:\.\d+)?ml`:

```
input = "L'Oreal Paris L'Huile Nail Paint, 224 Rose Ballet, 13.5ml"
matches = re.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(ml)', input)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[('13.5', 'ml')]
```

**Edit:**

To handle capturing a known *list* of units, you may modify the above regex pattern to the following:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:GM|KG|LIT)
```

This uses an alteration to represent each possible unit, and you may add new units as you see fit.

Comment: But this will only work for `ml` units. I assume that if he/she wants to save the `ml` in database is because it is not always `ml`

Comment: @Ivan Yes, I know this :-) ... my answer can easily be updated to match a more generic pattern for a unit.

Comment: @Ivan If the user giving the different units like GM,KG,LIT now how should i filter that value while it was running in loop

Comment: @pavithra Please check my updated answer, which gives you an option for handling more than one unit.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = "L'Oreal Paris L'Huile Nail Paint, 224 Rose Ballet, 13.5ml, 14dl"

for i in range(len(data)-1):
    try:
        # if number is before letter  
        int(data[i])
        if data[i+1].isalpha():
            data = data[:i+1] + ' ' + data[i+1:] # add space between number and letter
    except:
        pass

print (data)
```

output:

```
L'Oreal Paris L'Huile Nail Paint, 224 Rose Ballet, 13.5 ml, 14 dl
```